# Wie beugt man das Adjektiv „irreduzibel“?

Tags: declension, mathematics

Wie dekliniert man das Adjektiv *irreduzibel*? Die Endung *-ble* bei verschiedenen Fällen verwirrt mich. In etwa [diesem Wikipedia-Artikel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darstellungstheorie_%28Gruppentheorie%29) kann man sehen, worum es geht. Aus demselben Artikel lässt sich wohl dessen Starke Flektion herleiten (weil es in Wiktionary, DWDS und dict.cc nichts zu Deklination gab).

```
          Weiblich         Neutrum         Männlich          |   Plural
Nom.      irreduzible      irreduzibles    irreduziebler*    |   irreduzible
Gen.      irreduzibler         (?)             (?)           |   irreduzibler
Dat.      irreduzibler     irreduziblem*   irreduziblem*     |   irreduziblen
Akk.      irreduzible      irreduzibles    irreduziblen*     |   irreduzible
```

Bei den mit `*` markierten Einträgen bin ich aber unsicher. Bei den `(?)`-Einträgen habe ich überhaupt keine Ahnung.

Comment: Bezieht sich deine Frage jetzt speziell auf Adjektive auf *-ibel/-abel*? Gibt es einen Grund, warum du annimmst, das Adjektiv habe andere Endungen als [z. B. hier dargestellt](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Deklination#Starke_Deklination_der_Adjektive)? So wie ich es sehe, ist die einzige "Unregelmäßigkeit", dass sich -el- zu -le- verändert (ähnlich wie teu-er/teu-re(r/s/n/m).

Comment: [Ich will nicht arrogant klingen. Du schreibst fehlerfreies Deutsch und du kennst den Fachterminus *Starke Flexion*. Ich frage mich, wo das eigentliche Problem liegt. ;-)]

Comment: Ok, danke. Eben weil die Beugung unregelmäßig ist. Ich kann nicht wie bei *rot* einfach die üblichen Endungen hinzufügen. Aber ich hätte viellecht die Flektion aus (etwa) der von *komfortabel* folgern sollen ;) Da war die Antwort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canoo.net hat eine Flexionstabelle für *[irreduzibel](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/irreduzibel:A)*. (Ein Wort, was ich übrigens nicht kenne.)

Beachte, dass Adjektive unterschiedlich dekliniert werden, je nachdem ob sie mit bestimmten, unbestimmten oder ohne Artikel stehen.

Hier eine vollständige Auflistung für *irreduzibel*, hoffentlich ohne Tippfehler:

**Starke Flexion ohne Artikel**

```
      Männlich            Neutrum             Weiblich            Plural
Nom.  irreduzibler        irreduzibles        irreduzible         irreduzible
Akk.  irreduziblen        irreduzibles        irreduzible         irreduzible
Dat.  irreduziblem        irreduziblem        irreduzibler        irreduziblen
Gen.  irreduziblen        irreduziblen        irreduzibler        irreduzibler
```

**Schwache Flexion mit bestimmten Artikel**

```
      Männlich            Neutrum             Weiblich            Plural
Nom.  der irreduzible     das irreduzible     die irreduzible     die irreduziblen
Akk.  den irreduziblen    das irreduzible     die irreduzible     die irreduziblen
Dat.  dem irreduziblen    dem irreduziblen    der irreduziblen    den irreduziblen
Gen.  des irreduziblen    des irreduziblen    der irreduziblen    der irreduziblen
```

**Gemischte Flexion mit unbestimmten Artikel**

```
      Männlich            Neutrum             Weiblich            Plural
Nom.  ein irreduzibler    ein irreduzibles    eine irreduzible    keine irreduziblen
Akk.  einen irreduziblen  ein irreduzibles    eine irreduzible    keine irreduziblen
Dat.  einem irreduziblen  einem irreduziblen  einer irreduziblen  keine irreduziblen
Gen.  eines irreduziblen  eines irreduziblen  einer irreduziblen  keine irreduziblen
```

Comment: "Irreduzibel" ist ein Fachbegriff aus der Mathematik mit vielfachen Bedeutungen.